# Launch4j исключение

Tags: exe, java

Объясните пожалуйста почему при попытке создать exe-файл в утилите Launch4j появляется исключение:

```
net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j7123505325029323400rc C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j3286119615690412332o
```

**Лог:**

```
LANGUAGE 0, 1 1 
RCDATA BEGIN "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_101\\\0" END 18 
RCDATA BEGIN "1\0" END 30 
RCDATA BEGIN "2\0" END 1 ICON DISCARDABLE "C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Desktop\\w118h1201372352893tetris.ico" 21 
RCDATA BEGIN "http://java.com/download\0" END 8 RCDATA BEGIN ".\0" END 20 
RCDATA BEGIN "32\0" END 4 
RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END 5 
RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END 6 
RCDATA BEGIN "5\0" END 7 
RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END 1 BITMAP "C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Desktop\\splash.bmp" 101 
RCDATA BEGIN "An error occurred while starting the application.\0" END 102 RCDATA BEGIN "This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted.\0" END 103 
RCDATA BEGIN "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment\0" END 104 RCDATA BEGIN "The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.\0" END 105 
RCDATA BEGIN "An application instance is already running.\0" END 23 
RCDATA BEGIN "tetris\0" END 17 
RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END
```

Вроде как ругается на отсутствие JRE, но JRE то стоит, и путь к нему указан верно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело было в именах папок в пути к загрузочным изображениям - изменил русские имена на английские и все заработало